# Does the app side-menu navigation get slow when the list is huge?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Currently in my application, I have a side-menu(ION-MENU) and a screen that contains a large list of objects. I have noticed that there is a sluggishness in opening/closing the side menu when the size of the list in the screen is large. However when the size of the list is small the list side-menu or ION-Menu opens and closes pretty quickly. What would be the solution?

Currently I have the ION-MENU in my APP.HTML. I update the content of that in the app.component.ts. In my page I can swipe or click on the menu to get the side menu(ion-menu).

Expected result: Navigation to side-menu should be smooth irrespective of the data in the page on which the side-menu is over
Actual result: The Side-menu is sluggish and slow and needs to be smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course it could response slowly when the size of all objects is big.
There are 2 possible solutions. Choose the one that suits your needs.

1. Try to reduce the size of objects. E.g. you can try to remove
   properties of the objects that are irrelevant in that case.
2. Try to use infinite-scroll provided by Ionic. This means that you
   only load the new objects if the user is at the end of the scrolling
   list. You can find more infos [**here**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/):

Comment: What would the reason for that be? All the data is already loaded and being displayed. How is this affecting open/closing the side-menu? On a different note:  I have tried using infinite scroll, the thing is, I need to scroll to a particular index when the user clicks on something(Like the contacts application, when we click on a letter at the side, the view scrolls to the particular letter in the contacts list) so we are not able to use infinite scrolling. Do you have any possible solution?

Comment: Hi @LuqmaanTahaSiddiqui I have the exact same problem. Huge list, everything works just the menu is slow. Need to click-scroll as well so cannot load only parts. How did you solve it?